# Setting up email Notification on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, email-notifications

I have Self-hosted agents on my Azure DevOps on which the execution is scheduled from ADO every night using the release pipelines which i've created. I would want to send out email notification with the results to a Distribution List after the completion of the execution. How can i achieve this??

I want this summary page to be sent as an attachment -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Setting up email Notification on Azure DevOps

AFAIK, Azure devops does not support add attachment in email Notification directly.

As workaround, we could use a powershell script to get test results with REST API then send emails:

To get test results with RESI API [Releases - Get Task Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20task%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{releaseDeployPhaseId}/tasks/{taskId}/logs?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Then use powershell scripts to read the details of the test result file (.trx) and create a formatted email message to sent to the defined recipients:

You could check this thread [Send Test Result Email After Running Automated Tests with Release Management](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2015/10/send-test-result-email-after-running.html) for some details.

Hope this helps.